# Loss decreases when using semi hard triplets

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

[Here](https://www.slideshare.net/AdwinJahn1/review-of-triplet-learning) is a short review of triplet learning. 
I'm using three convolutional neural networks with shared weights in order to generate faces embeddings (**anchor**, **positive**, **negative**), with the loss described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260113/implementing-contrastive-loss-and-triplet-loss-in-tensorflow).

Triplet loss:

```
anchor_output = ...  # shape [None, 128]
positive_output = ...  # shape [None, 128]
negative_output = ...  # shape [None, 128]

d_pos = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor_output - positive_output), 1)
d_neg = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor_output - negative_output), 1)

loss = tf.maximum(0., margin + d_pos - d_neg)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

When I select only the hard triplets (`distance(anchor, positive) < distance(anchor, negative)`), the loss is very small: **0.08**.
When I select all triplets, the loss becomes bigger **0.17855**. These are just test values for 10 000 triplet pairs, but I get similar results on the actual set (600 000 triplet pairs).

Why does this happen? Is it correct?

I'm using SGD with momentum, starting with **learning rate 0.001**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick recap of the terminology on the hardness of triplets:

- **easy triplets**: triplets which have a loss of 0, because `d(a,p) + margin < d(a,n)`
- **hard triplets**: triplets where the negative is closer to the anchor than the positive, i.e. `d(a,n) < d(a,p)`
- **semi-hard triplets**: triplets where the negative is not closer to the anchor than the positive, but still has positive loss: `d(a, p) < d(a, n) < d(a, p) + margin`

[image]

What you describe here:

> When I select only the hard triplets (distance(anchor, positive) < distance(anchor, negative))

is actually selecting semi-hard triplets and easy triplets. You're removing the hard triplets, so your loss is smaller.